# drupal generate fpdf files

Tags: pdf, drupal, fpdf

I create website based on drupal 7 with module to generate pdf - i use fpdf library.
I dont know how I can make form to send some data to node where i have php code for generate pdf.
Also i still get error message:

```
FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at Z:\xampp\htdocs\domain\includes\common.inc:2748)
```

where i found:

```
ob_flush();
```

when i try change it to

```
ob_clean()
```

all nodes generate pdf :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try use other module which is a simple - [pdf_using_mpdf](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_using_mpdf)
With this module you can get PDF of some node calling www.YOUR_SITE.DOMAIN/node/NID_ID/pdf - where NID_ID is the id of node what you want to render as PDF.

Or also you can use hook_menu() if you need render as PDF only some fields of your node - add your item like

```
$items['%node/create_pdf'] = array(
   'title' => '',
   'description' => '',
   'page callback' => 'custom_callback_create_pdf',
   'page arguments' => array(1),
   'access callback' => 'node_access',
   'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

Define you callback like

```
function custom_callback_create_pdf($node) {
  // Check if current node has needed field.
  if (isset($node->field_my_custom_field_of_node)) {
  // Render only field 'field_my_custom_field_of_node';
    $view = node_view($node);
    $output = render($view['field_my_custom_field_of_node']);
    return pdf_using_mpdf_api($output, $node->title);
  }
  else {
    return pdf_using_mpdf_api("<html><body>Current page do not required field.</body></html>", $node->title);
  }
}
```

and print button for download:

```
$pdf_button = l(t('Download as PDF'), 'node/' . $node->nid . '/create_pdf', array(
    'attributes' => array(
      'target' => '_blank',
      'class' => array('render_as_pdf'),
    ),
  ));
  echo '<p>' . $pdf_button . '</p>';
```